# Virtual List is not populating in EF6

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4, entity-framework-6

virtual list is not populating for second row of data.
here is my model of userprofile

```
  [Table("UserProfile")]
   public class USRProfile
    {
        [Key]
        public int UserId { get; set; }
        [Required]
        public string UserName { get; set; }
        public int? IntroducerId { get; set; }
        [ForeignKey("IntroducerId")]
        public virtual USRProfile Introducer { get; set; }
        public virtual List<UserInRole> UserInRoles { get; set; }
        public virtual List<USRProfile> Members { get; set; }

    }
```

and my userinrole model

```
 [Table("webpages_UsersInRoles")]
    public class UserInRole
    {
        [Key]
        public int RoleId { get; set; }
        [ForeignKey("RoleId")]
        public virtual UserRole UserRole { get; set; }
        public int UserId { get; set; }
        [ForeignKey("UserId")]
        public virtual USRProfile User { get; set; }
    }
```

here is my query to get user

```
  public JsonResult GetUser(int id)
            {
                var usr = uRepository.USRProfiles.FirstOrDefault(c => c.UserId == id);
                var seconusrrole = usr.Members[1].UserInRoles;
                //here seconusrrole is null, but called individually it get data.
                return Json(, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
            }
```

is this a bug of or am I doing somthing wrong?

Comment: Please show an example of the returned data to showcase the problem you're seeing. The question at the top of your question says "not populating for the *second* row of data", but your query at the bottom is a `FirstOrDefault`, meaning there is now "second row".

Comment: What kind of mapping you want? 1 to n or n to n.

Comment: Inner virtual class Member having more than one row and in Member[0] UserInRoles Virtual is populating but after that it shows null

Comment: I simply used the by default created database by WebSecurity of MVC 4, It's 1 to n, as one Usercan have multiple roles.

Answer (score 0):

You are not loading related entities

```
// using System.Data.Entity.Core.Objects;
var usr = uRepository.USRProfiles.Include(x => x.Members.Select(y => y.UserInRoles))
                                 .FirstOrDefault(c => c.UserId == id);

var seconusrrole = usr.Members[1].UserInRoles;
```

See Microsoft post for more information: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-ca/data/jj574232.aspx

**Edit**

You must add the "System.Data.Entity.Core.Objects" namespace to include with expressions.

The include method is an extension methods on IQueryable<T>.

Comment: In my no need to use Include as there isn't any function like .Include in DbContext

Comment: I'm not sure to understand your comment. The include method is used with IQueryable not DbContext, to include with expression you must add the namespace "System.Data.Entity.Core.Objects".